# Jboss Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Tags: deployment, jboss, geoserver

when i tried to deploy my geoserver 2.9 war file in jboss 1.7.1..it showing the following error..

```
Unknown error

Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "geoserver.war")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./geoserver" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./geoserver: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

How can I solve this??

Comment: 500 is an internal Server error. See the logfiles for more informations

Answer (score 0):

JBoss is a pain to deploy on, first you need to follow the [GeoServer documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/jboss/jboss_tutorial.html):

> To install geoserver onto JBoss AS 5.1, the following is required:
>
> Create the file jboss-classloading.xml with the following content then
>   copy it into the WEB-INF directory in the geoserver.war:

```
<classloading
 xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
         name="geoserver.war"
         domain="GeoServerDomain"> </classloading>
```

> Extract the hsqldb-2.2.8.jar file from the WEB-INF/lib directory from the
>   geoserver.war and copy it as hsqldb.jar to the common/lib directory in
>   the JBoss deployment. Add the following text to the WEB-INF/web.xml
>   file in the geoserver.war so that JBoss logging does not end up in the
>   geoserver.log:

```
     <context-param>
         <param-name>RELINQUISH_LOG4J_CONTROL</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value> 
     </context-param>
```

And then I seem to recall having to unpack the GeoServer war and remove some jars that JBoss had already placed into common - though that was a few years back and may have related to other wars we we also deploying.